# for loop to calculate students' average mark. my average keeps on adding up

Tags: java

I had this assignment which I need to use Java to create a for-loop to calculate the average of each students' score. The teacher must enter number of test score per student and the loop will then iterate for each student.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class average {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int count = 0;
        int student;
        int sum = 0;
        int grade;
        int average = 0;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of students:");
        student = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter number of test scores per student: ");
        count = keyboard.nextInt();

        for (int s = 0; s < student; s++) {
            System.out.println("Student number " + (s + 1) );

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter score no." + (i + 1) + " : ");
                grade = keyboard.nextInt();
                sum += grade; 
                average = sum/count;

            }

            System.out.println("The average is " + average);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: reset the `sum` to 0 on each iteration

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: `count` seem to be always equal to `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sum = 0 after printing average

Just shown in below loop

```
for (int s = 0; s < student; s++) {
        System.out.println("Student number " + (s + 1));


        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter score no." + (i + 1) + " : ");
            grade = keyboard.nextInt();
            sum += grade;
            average = sum / count;

        }

        System.out.println("The average is " + average);

        sum = 0;  //THIS IS REQUIRED
    }
```